# Canon and JLD files

Tags: printing, reverse-engineering, printers

I have a problem with reading printed jobs on my printer via script. Canon changed website of my printer on dynamic and using cookies. I don't have answer from Canon yet, but I found a program named Canon Accounting Manager, which can download jobs from printer. But this program can download jobs automatically only daily. I need it every minute. I looked into directories and found, that program makes jld files. But when I try it open with julia

```
julia> using JLD
julia> d = jldopen("/home/martin/test.jld")
ERROR: /home/martin/test.jld does not seem to be a Julia data or HDF5 file
Stacktrace:
 [1] #jldopen#9(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool) at /home/martin/.julia/v0.6/JLD/src/JLD.jl:220
 [2] (::JLD.#kw##jldopen)(::Array{Any,1}, ::JLD.#jldopen, ::String, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0
 [3] #jldopen#10(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at /home/martin/.julia/v0.6/JLD/src/JLD.jl:231
 [4] jldopen(::String) at /home/martin/.julia/v0.6/JLD/src/JLD.jl:231
```

So this is pretty simple answer from julia, but how can I identify a type of file? Answer of `file`

```
martin@MARWIN:~$ file test.jld
test.jld: data
```

Have somebody idea, how can  open it? Or some link on printer Canon, where is simple list of printed jobs?

Comment: I would wager quite a bit of money that they're not using Julia's JLD but rather a proprietary format.  Best way to look into it is with `xxd` and examine the first bytes very closely.

Comment: I tried: `martin@MARWIN:~$ xxd -l 1024 test.jld` and i got:
`00000000: 2c76 045a 0000 0000 0100 0100 0100 0000  ,v.Z............`
`00000010: 0100 0000 f400 0000 10eb eb2e dd60 2e6a  ..............j`
`00000020: 00eb 2e90 41eb 2e7c ebeb 2e6a dd1c 2e00  ....A..|...j....`
`00000030: d82e d81c eb2e 6a7c eb2e 006a 1c2e 0060  ......j|...j...`
`00000040: 2e6a 601c 2eeb 3b0e 0e97 ba2e 977a 97fa  .j...;......z..`
`00000050: 292e 902e 0060 7c1c 902e 007c 41eb ebeb  )....|....|A...`
`00000060: 2ed8 7c41 902e eb2e 0000 411c 902e 0000`
....
I will try to find something. Thanks